# Не отображаются данные в dataGridView2

Tags: c#, sql

Проблема такова...
есть dataGridView2 на Form2

На главное форме Form1 пишу вот так...
чтобы данные отобразились на Form2 в dataGridView2

Но нечего не происходит. Код работает. А данных нет! В dataGridView2
Исправьте код... буду благодарен.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace 123
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // строка соединения с базой данных
        string ConnStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Allah\akbar.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

  public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Fill1();   
             Fill2();   
        }

        public void MyExecuteNonQuery(string SqlText)
        {
            SqlConnection cn; // экземпляр класса типа SqlConnection
            SqlCommand cmd;

            // выделение памяти с инициализацией строки соединения с базой данных
            cn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
            cn.Open(); // открыть источник данных
            cmd = cn.CreateCommand(); // задать SQL-команду
            cmd.CommandText = SqlText; // задать командную строку
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // выполнить SQL-команду
            cn.Close(); // закрыть источник данных
        }

        // Показать таблицу 
        private void Fill2()
        {
            string SqlText = "SELECT * FROM [ttttt]";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlText, ConnStr);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "[tttttt]");
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["[tttttt]"].DefaultView;
        }
```

Comment: **На главное форме Form1 пишу вот так... чтобы данные отобразились на Form2** а почему код привязка не пишите на `Form2`?.`Grid` же там??

Comment: ну, если вы уверены, что только >> *В dataGridView2 Исправьте код...*, а всё остальное правильно :)  5 или 6 букв **t** в `[имени_таблицы]`?

Comment: @ Vardan Vardanyan вот хочу на Form1. Нельзя? Или не логично?

Comment: @Alias дело в том, что там есть 3 таблицы и 1 будет на Form2, по этому и прошу поправить код

Comment: да конечно, описанную правку кода из ответа Vardan Vardanyan необходимо повторить для всех форм и соответствующих таблиц :)

Answer (score 2):

Класс `DataGridView` поддерживает стандартную модель **Windows Forms** привязки данных. Это означает, что источник данных может быть любого типа, который реализует один из следующих интерфейсов

- Интерфейс `IList`, включающий одномерные массивы.
- Интерфейс `IListSource`, такой как классы `DataTable и DataSet`.
- Интерфейс `IBindingList`, такой как класс `BindingList<T>`.
- Интерфейс `IBindingListView`, такой как класс `BindingSource`.

Обычно привязка осуществляется к компоненту `BindingSource`, а компонент `BindingSource` привязывается к другому источнику данных или *заполняется бизнес-объектами*. Компонент `BindingSource` является предпочтительным источником данных, так как обеспечивает привязку к различным источникам данных и может автоматически разрешать различные проблемы привязки данных.

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = new DataTable();
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1
```

Вот вам статья с примером [Свойство DataSource в DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)